# Ubuntu Live CD Not Loading Properly - Hangs on Ubuntu Screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, live-cd

I am the second owner of a Everex Stepnote SA2052T laptop with Intel Core Duo processor, 1.6 GHz,1 GB, and American Megatrends, Inc. BIOS V 02.59. According the the labelling, it came with Windows Vista, but the 80 GB Fujitsu HD appears to have been partitioned 2 X 40GB.  I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 and would like to upgrade to 10.04 using the live CD method, since OS's are end of life. I want to run 10.04 in the live mode from a CD to confirm that it is compatible with my laptop's hardware. I have found that others have had problems loading Ubuntu on Everex computers:  http://poplarware.com/articles/everex_stepnote_linux. My goal is to install the most up to date compatible Ubuntu upgrade on this machine that I am able to. I have a 10.04 and a 11.04 Live CD, neither of which works in the Everex, but both Live CDs boot to completion in my Lenovo Ideapad Y510 laptop.  With the Everex, attempts to boot with either CD stall at the Ubuntu splash screen, at a point prior to the cursor arrow ever appearing on the screen.  I've tried each of the boot options available in the "Advanced Welcome Page" https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions under the F6 menu; nolapic, edd=on, nodraid, etc.  I'm at the end of my abilities, which do not currently include command line or terminal operations.

Comment: The most up-to-date version of Ubuntu you can run on that computer is..... the latest. We've all forgotten how those EOL releases work, so we can't help you with them :p. However, we can certainly help if you have an issue with 14.04 or 15.10.

Comment: I think this is on topic. The OP is attempting to run the latest release they can, we can help them with that. OP: Have you tried 12.04, 14.04 or 15.10?

Comment: I haven't tried anything newer than 11.04 yet, but that sounds like a good idea.   I'll need to get some more blank DVDs first.  Thanks.

Comment: … or use a USB drive with ≥ 2 GiB of space.